# Garbage Collection Kick In Took So Long [Intermittent] - Stop-the-world

Tags: .net, .net-core, garbage-collection, dotmemory

I ran an application using .NET in Raspberry Pi 4, I track the memory using DotMemory. I found interesting pattern.

| No | Unmanaged Memory | Heap generation 0 | Objects | GC Times |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 134.25 | 495.9 | 7.3K | 8 sec |
| 2 | 134.21 | 647.7 | 8.4K | < 1 sec |

The data in No.1 -- Sometimes(occured 10 times @2 hour), the Garbage Collection Kick In took so long (Stop-the-world), I'm not sure what the root cause of the issue. The Objects and Heap Generation 0 is lower than No.2 which took only < 1 sec.

[The Yellow Bar is GC Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ihdE.png)

To reduce the issue, we make sure IDisposable object is disposed, reduce BeginScope log, etc. The behavior reduced from 10times@2hour to 5times@2hour. But we're still not sure what is the root cause why pattern No.1 exist in our dotMemoryProfiler.

We're trying to understand the root cause and reduce this pattern as much as possible.

Comment: GC only starts if there is memory pressure. Is there an issue? Why does it matter to you if GC runs late if you have enough RAM? If you have memory pressure that GC isn't picking up on please explain how you know that. Have tried switching to Server-Mode GC?

Comment: We use this for robot -- Raspi4 , so real time processing is needed. Delay  or Stop-the-world for 8 sec resulting issues. Server-Mode GC is not suitable for this case.

Again, what we do want to know is why it can happened as intermittent. If you read the data, it doesn't make sense when greater objects and gen 0 took < 1sec while sometimes lesser objects and gen 0 took more than 5 seconds

Comment: .NET is not a real-time system, so you aren't really using the right tool for the job. 8 seconds to run GC on 7300 objects is far too long either way, even 1 second is too long. Perhaps there is another underlying issue, such as faulty RAM or paging to disk (one way to prevent slow memory is to switch off paging). Obviously if you can reduce the number of objects you are creating then GC will run less often.